# Есть ли способ приведения целочилсенных типов к строке байт, помимо отделения битов с помощью побитовых операций?

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Есть ли способо приведения целочисленных типов кстроке байт? Вот как пример, есть число, например максимальное от unsigned long, это 8байт, если я не ошибаюсь, есть ли возможность разложить это число на байты без отделения каждого байта с помощью побитовых операций?

Comment: Что такое строка байт, как она выглядит и как вы её использовать хотите? Приведите пример плиз.

Comment: @Kromster, обычный массив чаров/бесзнаковых чаров, содержащий в себе байты unsigned чаров, вот пример разложения с помощью побитовых операций
    for (ssize_t i = 2; i < frameSize; i++)
        frame[i] = 0;
    for (int i = frameSize - 1; size != 0; i--)
    {
        frame[i] = size & 0xFF;
        size >>= 8;
    }

Comment: Под вопросом, кнопка "править"

Comment: Какова **реальная** задача? Чем плохи побитовые операции?

Comment: @MBo, Распарсить и отослать frame протокола веб соккет. В побитовых операциях нет ничего плохого, есь рабочий вариант на си с ними, но в с++ хотелось бы использовать бит сет, который позволяет получить знаечние битовго вектор в unsigned long, и нехотелось бы прибегать к низкоуровневым побитовым операциям.

Comment: @DenverToha,  возможно на самом деле вам нужны [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно! Для этого специальный тип данных **union** и создавался в Си. Вот пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

union Data {
    uint64_t uint64;
    uint8_t uint8[8];
};
typedef union Data Data_t;

int main()
{
    char i;
    Data_t data;
    data.uint64 = -1; 
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d ", data.uint8[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Пояснения по коду:

1) Если беззнаковому присвоить -1, то это приведёт к установке всех битов в 1.

2) После выполнения программы увидим: 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 (т.е 8 байтов подряд)

3) Вроде, каким образом хранятся байты в union в массиве - вначале старший или вначале младший это машиннозависимо и надо тестировать, но это не точно.

Comment: Это точно машиннозависимо.

Comment: А это строго соответствует стандарту? Такое разрешено - писать как один тип, читать как другой? Говорили вроде, что такое как `unsigned char * arr = (unsigned char *)&ulong` запрещено...